# how to convert special chars with Unicode?

Tags: c#, .net

How can I convert string with special chars, like this:
`małoletni => ma\u0142oletni`
Where `ł` converts into `\u0142` (the same with rest special chars).

I've tried with

`System.Text.UnicodeEncoding encoding = new System.Text.UnicodeEncoding();`

but it returns strange results.

How can I convert it?

Comment: There are no _special_ chars in Unicode anymore, that's why it's so nice :D

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "małoletni\nPi(π)";

//ESCAPE
var escaped = String.Join("", str.Select(c => c>31 && c < 128 ? c.ToString() : "\\u" + ((int)c).ToString("x4")));

//UNESCAPE
var unescaped = Regex.Unescape(escaped)
```